# How to make ASP.NET Core return XML result?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GetXml(string value)
{
    var xml = $"<result><value>{value}</value></result>";
    return new HttpResponseMessage
   {
       Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml")
   };
}
```

I called the action using Swagger and passed this parameter 'text value'

**Expected** result should be an XML file like this: text value

**Actual Result:** strange json result without the passed value! https://www.screencast.com/t/uzcEed7ojLe

I tried the following solutions but did not work:

```
services.AddMvc().AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
services.AddMvc().AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

Comment: are you declaring this two attributes together [HttpGet]
[HttpPost] ?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a different beast to the old Web API, it does not natively work with or understand `HttpResponseMessage`. I also made the migration from web API -> Core and had to unlearn a lot of things like that before it started making sense to me.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this solution

```
[HttpGet]
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult GetXml(string value)
{
    var xml = $"<result><value>{value}</value></result>";
    return new ContentResult
    {
        Content = xml,
        ContentType = "application/xml",
        StatusCode = 200
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. you are missing parameter in your attribute.
2. you can put produces attribute to declare what type of output format
3. you can embrace IActionResult or directly return ContentResult.

   ```
   [HttpGet("{value}")]
   [Produces("application/xml")]
   public IActionResult GetXml(string value)
   {
       var xml = $"<result><value>{value}</value></result>";
       //HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
       //response.Content = new StringContent(xml, Encoding.UTF8);
       //return response;

       return new ContentResult{
           ContentType = "application/xml",
           Content = xml,
           StatusCode = 200
       };
   }
   ```

The above will give you

```
<result>
    <value>hello</value>
</result>
```

you can refer to following link to understand more about IActionResult

[What should be the return type of WEB API Action Method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39844418/what-should-be-the-return-type-of-web-api-action-method)

Answer (score 1):

For ASP.NET core 2+, you need to configure [`XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.xmldatacontractserializeroutputformatter?view=aspnetcore-3.0), it could be found from [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc(c =>
    {
        c.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
    });
}
```