# Setting the API to accept XML for output format

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I wanted to see if I can havew my `API` return `"XML"` so I changed the `Accept Header` to XML like this pic below :
[image]

And I updated my code like this below.  But still it returns `JSON` :  Why?

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

I was following a PluralSight course that was doing this and worked for him.

Comment: how does your controller looked like?

Comment: @BagusTesa oh you were right! my controller was still saying return new JaonResult !!  LOL ... OK that fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You can also annotate your controller with ` .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();` (in your services configuration) and `Produces("application/xml")]`: (annotate your controller): https://stackoverflow.com/a/59191378/421195

Comment: If you want to support clients that can't / won't set the accept header, I'd recommend an explicit format parameter in the url `[FormatFilter, Route(".../name.{format}")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I updated my code like this below. But still it returns JSON :
> Why?

According to your description and shared snippet I have tired to simulate your issue and its working as expected. In addition, I can switch between XML and Json response from the header value.

You can refer to following sample:

Demo Model:

```
public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Demo Controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CityXMLController : ControllerBase
    {
        public IActionResult GetCity()
        {
            var cityList = new List<City>()
            {
                new City { Id = 101, Name = "Alberta" },
                new City { Id = 102, Name = "Toronto" },
                new City { Id = 103, Name = "British Comlombia" },
            };
            return Ok(cityList);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** Please make sure you are [using Ok as return type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.results.ok?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in order to handle dynamic request header both (XML and Json) because, specific return type would fail opposite response type as per header value.

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
}).AddXmlDataContractSerializerFormatters();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Accept header configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-accept-header-2) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#the-accept-header-2).